# Magento 1.7- value of the new added field isn't shown on the backend after registration

Tags: magento

I have added a field on both frontend and backend called 'Association'. However, The data wasn't shown on the Customers-> Manage customers of the backend after user completed registration.

The 'association' also added into Table 'eav_attribute'. How can I make the value displayed on the backend? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you add the field, could you provide more details?